# Почему не работает гем breadcrumbs_on_rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Делаю всё по чётко по инструкции как у автора гема: https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails
Начал уже создавать даже контроллер как у него с тем же названием.
Вобщем мне выдаёт вот такую ошибку:

```
undefined method `add_breadcrumb' for MyController:Class
```

Как пофиксить? 
**версия руби:** ruby 2.1.8p440 (2015-12-16 revision 53160) [x86_64-linux]

**версия рельс:** Rails 4.2.5.1

Comment: Можете привести, как точно выглядит сейчас ваш контроллер? Просто в примерах, он например, не наследуется от ActionController::Base. Не может быть в этом дело?